# Power in my house is not all working,only half

Tags: electrical

How to tell what's wrong  with power in my house from the meters outside. Half house power is off and on with no tripped breakers

Answer (score 6):

Call the utility, and have them come check the service drop.  If that doesn't resolve it, contact a local licensed Electrician.

There's not much troubleshooting a DIYer can do in this situation, especially if the problem is with the service.